# How to add a background image to the area outside the body

Tags: css, background

Hi I have a normal html website and wanted to add a background image to the area outside the body tag.

So far I have this in my css

```
#class:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-image:url(../images/Background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then I added the div above the body .. obviously have gone amiss somewhere as it doesnt work.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you please  describe what is the desired visual + behaviour of your website, I'm sure that I can help you achieve that by setting background image inside the body tag.

Comment: Hi please see screenshot.  http://www.broomedaycare.com/images/gradient-outside-body-content.jpg

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `flex`

I've create a JSFiddle for you: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/n6dzvL7L/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="width-200 bg-red">
        Put here your background
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1">
          right panel
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
  height:500px;
}

.flex-1{
  flex:1;
  padding-left:10px; 
  background-color:white;
}

.width-200{
  width:200px;
}

.bg-red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand that this will work.  How will 2 divs place the background outside the body?

Comment: they will be inside the body tag.  l've updated the code example